# Does ActiveObject still work after applets update?

Tags: java

Using objectDraw, you can extend either WindowController or ActiveObject, WindowController for various different imputs, and ActiveObject that runs independantly of those inputs.

Ive been told Java doesnt use applets anymore so it makes a lot of code not work, but here is the old code that would have worked if Java wasnt updated:

```
import objectdraw.*;
// animate the motion of a simple, falling ball
public class BouncingBall extends ActiveObject
{
// size and speed of balls
private static final double BALLSIZE = 30;
private static final double DELAY_TIME = 33;
private double ySpeed = 0.1;

// y coordinate where ball disappears
private double bottom;

// the ball
private FilledOval ball;

// the paddle
private FilledRect paddle;

public BouncingBall(double x, double y, FilledRect thePaddle, DrawingCanvas aCanvas)
{
    
    ball = new FilledOval(x - BALLSIZE/2 , y,
                          BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE, aCanvas);
    bottom = aCanvas.getHeight();
    paddle = thePaddle;
}

public void run()
{
    double lastTime, currentTime, elapsedTime;
    // remember the time;
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    double top = ball.getY();
    
    // move the ball repeatedly until it fall off screen
    while (ball.getY() < bottom ) {
 
        // determine how much time has passed
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
        // restart timing
        lastTime = currentTime;
        ball.move(0, ySpeed * elapsedTime);
        
        if (ball.overlaps(paddle) || ball.getY() < top){
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;
        }
        pause(DELAY_TIME);
    }
    
    ball.removeFromCanvas();
}    
}
```

Here is a working example of WindowController, updated.

```
import objectdraw.*;

public class MakeBox extends WindowController {
    public void begin() {
        new FilledRect(0,0,30,30,canvas);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       new MakeBox().startController(400,400);
   
    }
}
```

Just adding a main class and running startController doesnt work, and currently the top program only creates a canvas with a small black box.

Any ideas on how to update it are invaluable. Likewise if you know a solution that would connect a working windowsController to it, that would work aswell.

Thank You

Comment: `ActiveObject` and `WindowController` are not classes that come with Java itself. They seem to be from some library named `objectdraw`. You'll have to check the documentation of that library to see what it requires. And if something "doesn't work", then telling us what exactly that looks like (what error message or wrong behaviour do you get?) will definitely help with finding a solution.

Comment: Yeah biggest issue is that it runs, just doesn't preform what its supposed to do

Comment: Well, then **maybe** you could describe to us what it's *supposed to do* and also *what it does*. You're letting us guess and it's really up to you to provide information for us to help you. Read [ask], it might be useful.